# Show inline field validation errors along with email sent message to an end user filling up a form

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm working on an app being developed on Nodejs, Expressjs, Mongoose stack.
I'm building a form on submission of which if there are some validation errors[ want to use only mongoose validation, just to keep validation code at one place] then re-render these error messages back to form and if all fields are valid then send an email to end user if that email is not already available in mongoose.

So this form is very usual form except I'm doing rendering this form by expressjs and also want that enduser should get the info that there are field errors also send an email and notify the end user at the same time that email is in process of being sent, and if email already exists then notify the user instantly on form.

Some psuedocode which can help me to think in Nodejs way would be much appreciated. I'm coming from python/Django stack.

Below is email sender module which returns a promise object.

**mailer.js**

```
var path           = require('path')
, templatesDir   = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'email_templates')
, emailTemplates = require('email-templates')
, nodemailer     = require('nodemailer')
, rsvp           = require('rsvp')
;

var sendEmail = function (template_name, locals) {
return new rsvp.Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    emailTemplates(templatesDir, function(err, template) {
      if (err) {
        return reject({error: err})
      } else {

        emailFrom = 'an_email_address', 
        mailer = {
            host: 'some_amazon_instance',
            port: 25,
            service: 'SMTP', // Gmail, SMTP, Zoho
            auth: {
                user: 'credential',
                pass: 'credential'
            }
        };

        var transport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", mailer);
        var emailTo = emailFrom;
        if (!locals.admin) {
          emailTo = locals.email;
        }

        // Send a single email
        template(template_name, locals, function(err, html, text) {
          if (err) {
          } else {
            transport.sendMail({
              from: emailFrom,
              to: emailTo,
              subject: locals.title,
              html: html,
              text: text
            }, function(err, responseStatus) {
              if (err) {
                transport.close();
                return reject({error: err});
              } else {
                resolve({result: responseStatus.message});
              }
              transport.close();
            });
          }
        });
      }
    });
});
}

exports.sendEmail = sendEmail;
```

Below is the mongoose model to handle form data, validation and email sending.

**invite.js**

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
   , Schema = mongoose.Schema
   , sendEmail = require('meanio').loadConfig().sendEmail
   , rsvp   = require('rsvp')
   ;

var StudioInviteSchema = new Schema({
name: {
    type: String, required: [true, 'name is required']
},
email: {
    type: String,
    index: true, 
    unique: true,
    required: [true, 'email is required']
},
phone: {
    type: Number,
    index: true, 
    unique: true, 
    required: [true, 'phone is required']
},
address: {
    type: String, required: [true, 'address is required']
},
email_template: {type: String, required: true},
title: {type: String, require: true}
});

StudioInviteSchema.path('phone').validate(function (value) {
 return parseInt(value)!=NaN && value.toString().length == 10;
}, 'Enter a valid phone number');


StudioInviteSchema.path('email').validate(function (value) {
  var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|    (\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
 return re.test(value)
}, 'Enter a valid email');

StudioInviteSchema.methods = {
saveAndEmailToAdmin: function () {
    var instance = this;
    console.log(instance, this, 42);
    return new rsvp.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        instance.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                if (err.code == 11000) {
                    return reject({message: 'duplicate invite'})
                }
                return reject({message: err})
            }

            var admin_email_context = {
                name: instance.name,
                email: instance.email,
                phone: instance.phone,
                address: instance.address,
                title: instance.title,
                admin: true
            }

            var studio_email_context = {
                name: instance.name,
                message: "We'll contact you shortly",
                email: instance.email,
                title: 'invite received',
                admin: false
            }

            var admin_email = sendEmail(instance.email_template, admin_email_context)
            var studio_email = sendEmail('userinvite', studio_email_context)

            rsvp.allSettled([admin_email, studio_email])
                .then(function (array) {
                    console.log(array)
                    resolve({message: 'success'})
                }, function (error) {
                    resolve({message: 'error'})
                })

        })
    });
}
};

mongoose.model('StudioInvite', StudioInviteSchema);
```

And finally below is the controller of html view which invoke `saveAndEmailToAdmin` of invite.js model for form validation and email sending.

**invite_controller.js**

```
exports.studioInvite = function (req, res) {
  var invite = new StudioInvite({
name: req.body.name,
email: req.body.email,
phone: req.body.phone,
address: req.body.address,
email_template: 'studioinvite',
title: 'Invite request from studio'
  });

  /*
  TODO:
have to use notifications to send messages to end users
like invite is sent successfully or there is some duplicacy
  */
  invite.saveAndEmailToAdmin()
    .then(function (result) {
  console.log(result)
  return [ send success messages ]
}, function (error) {
  console.log(error);
  return [ send error messages]
});

return [ i dont want to return at this line but if email sending takes time then have to return a response ]

}
```

I've found that i can use blocking code that means i've to put the user on hold untill everything is done on server, also I can use socket.io to send realtime notifications to end users about validation messages and email sent notifications.
But solution doesn't seem good to me.

Comment: @staaar, i've added the code. its a simple form but i'm not able to find a simpler way of showing the validation messages [mongoose validations not from controller] and how to notify user that email is sent. This trouble is all because i'm using promises.

Comment: Are you open for another npm module that integrates with ExpressJS, that could work with your app?

Comment: please let me know, i guess you're talking about validate library, there is also a message library for expressjs.